# Xcode "Size to fit contents" disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, resize

I am following the Stanford lectures on developing apps for iOS and I've run into a bit of a problem.
The lecturer says to click on a label from the Document Outline and then go to Editor > Size to fit contents in order to remove the fixed size constraints. However my problem is that "Size to fit contents" is disabled and I cannot click it (see image).

[image: disabled size to fit contents]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: click an empty area in your storyboard, then click the label again. That usually helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fixed the issue by dragging around the labels and resizing them (randomly) manually and then the option was enabled!

Comment: you can also clear all constraints to that label or any UIView with button `Resolve Auto Layout Issues`→`Clear Constraints` in IB, in Xcode 5+.

Answer (score 12):

OK this is one that has bugged me for a while.  But I finally figured out that if you tap one of the corner handles of the label (you will briefly see a diagonal line mouse icon for resizing) then the "size to fit contents" option is re-enabled.

This also works for getting the "horizontal rule" and "vertical rule" options back if you tap on one of the corner handles of a view.